# PHP & C++ Send / Receive Events

Tags: php, jquery, c++, node.js, sockets

I am trying to Send / Receive Events With PHP And C++

Example
Send Data From C++ And Receive it in realtime in my admin panel

Send Data From Php To My C++ Application and receive it in realtime

I tried Many things Like Send / Receive Data Via Sockets

Also Tried socket.io.js , Tried Jquery > WebSocket Too

Also i read about Send / Receive HTTP Request

I always stuck in receive data in realtime :(

After i send Data with socket to My Php Script i have to refresh the page to get data

Another Note : if i used socket everything i try to receive data after (Refresh) i have to reconnect to socket, i wanted to connect just one time then wait for response (waiting for the data without use while loop cuz it will keep page in loading)

C++ : Is Server

PHP : Is Client

Is there any suggestion about that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server side scripting language. It's not going to be able to process data 'realtime' unless your communicating with the client (in this case, a webbrowser). The best way to do this is via javascript. Either PHP or your C++ client can respond to requests from some javascript.

I've done this using websockets, however this required HTML5, which will only work with the latest browsers. At the backend (server side) I used node.js. You can see a working example via:

- https://github.com/jamesjenner/videre
- https://github.com/jamesjenner/videre-server.js

However the above are quite complex examples (also the server is easier to use in linux due to some dependencies that are difficult to compile on the latest 64-bit versions of windows).

As your starting out, I would suggest looking at the node.js plugin: https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node

It has an example shown on the doco for the above link that I believe will cover your query.

:edit

If you wish to support older browsers then I would suggest using javascript to perform regular http queries to your server. Then you can use your php to reply to the queries and use javascript to manipulate your DOM so that your webpage is updated automatically.

Here is an example of using javascript to get data from the server and show an alert using JSON as the data format: http://www.caveofprogramming.com/frontpage/articles/php/php-json-an-example-javascript-json-client-with-php-server/

Comment: If i will use socket, TO send data from c++ Server to Client (Javascript Or Jquery) What is the best functions to use it to receive sockets With Javascript or Jquery

Comment: You need to connect to your c++ server from the client (web browser) via Javascript. It's up to you what is best. If your c++ server supports http then I would suggest just poll regularly (or via user interaction). Websocket libs for c++ may be mature now, but I investigated them a year ago and they were not very good. There are tonnes of examples on how to use javascript to query a web server. That will most prob. be the easiest thing for you to do.

Comment: I've added a link to an example using javascript to query the server and display an alert based on the data received from the server (the server is running php).

Comment: Php is the server in this example and used : json_encode($data) to send data to client in json , c++ is my server so i used ___ char *sendbuf = "Message Sent From C++ Server To Client (Successfully)";
send( mySocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );  so how i will receive it with javascript in client :( sorry if i annoy you .. but i searched much about receive sockets with jquery or javascript and found WebSocket but failed to receive correct data , so a small example with javascript to connet / receive socket will be good